# I am stuck on grub rescue! I can't even execute the insmod command. An error says "error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: grubrescue

Can anybody provided me some help right now I'm not quite knowledgeable on grub commands so can some help me restore Ubuntu. I was just using the terminal and opened software update app. And the next thing you know it went to a black screen and started to write a bunch of weird stuff and then when I rebooted,the grub screen show now. Every time. Please help ty☺️

Comment: I'd boot *live* media (such as Ubuntu installation media) on your machine, and perform *file-system* checks using the appropriate commands for your *unstated* file-systems. If any errors are detected (*which would explain the error message you talk about & grubrescue*) and fixed, you'll almost certainly get a normal boot after the fix. Otherwise I'd be checking your hardware for faults for your unstated Ubuntu product/release. Giving full details as to what you're running, allows us to be more specific with advice.

Comment: Yeah understandable. Thanks for the advice. I don't remember what OS I installed, but it was from online via bootable USB.

Comment: If standard install, you may need fsck on all the ext4 partition(s). You can do that from live installer or same USB you used to install Ubuntu. If hardware issue, you may need to run Smartmon which you can access from Disks. And you can show us details of your install with Boot-Repair report. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486365/ubuntu-efi-not-mounted-in-correct-partition-but-opens-in-ro-mode